# Ambiguous substring with mismatches

Tags: python, regex, pypi-regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to find a substring in a string of DNA. This substring has ambiguous bases, that like `ATCGR`, where `R` could be `A` or `G`. Also, the script must allow `x` number of mismatches. So this is my code

```
import regex

s = 'ACTGCTGAGTCGT'    
regex.findall(r"T[AG]T"+'{e<=1}', s, overlapped=True)
```

So, with one mismatch I would expect 3 substrings `AC**TGC**TGAGTCGT` and `ACTGC**TGA**GTCGT` and `ACTGCTGAGT**CGT**`. The expected result should be like this:

```
['TGC', 'TGA', 'AGT', 'CGT']
```

But the output is

```
['TGC', 'TGA']
```

Even using re.findall, the code doesn't recognize the last substring.
On the other hand, if the code is setting to allow 2 mismatches with {e<=2}, the output is

```
['TGC', 'TGA']
```

Is there another way to get all the substrings?

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please have a read of [MCVE] to help improve your questions and increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @leleonp: works well for me except that you have to use `regex.findall` instead of `regex.search` if you want the two matches. As an aside writing *"the code doesn't work"* doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But findall doesn't seems to work with all the occurrences of the substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you are looking for all three letters substrings that match the pattern `T[GA]T` and you allow at worst one *error*, but I think the error you are looking for is only a character substitution since you never spoke about 2 letters results.

To obtain the expected result, you have to change `{e<=1}` to `{s<=1}` *(or `{s<2}`)* and to apply it to the whole pattern (and not only the last letter) enclosing it in a group (capturing or not capturing, like you want), otherwise the predicate `{s<=1}` is only linked to the last letter:

```
regex.findall(r'(T[AG]T){s<=1}', s, overlapped=True)
```